# Two laravel relationships on the same call

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have a Usercontract table and model... and I can call the usercontracts with it's relationships like this

```
return UserContract
        ::with(['contracttax', 'contractproperty', 'persons', 'contractwarranty', 'users', 'contracts', 'tags'])
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
```

Then I have another user model with this method.

```
public function nonAcceptedContracts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(UserContract::class, 'invite', 'email', 'usercontract', 'email')->where('status', 'pending');
}
```

Is there a way to call this "nonAcceptedContracts" together with the rest of the relationships from Usercontract? So I end up with all the results together on the same variable?

Comment: You can call nested relationships like `->with([..., 'users.nonAcceptedContracts'])`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank youuu... I'm just getting into an already developed laravel project with no idea about laravel hehe. Write the answer so I set it like the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel allows you to chain relationships. In your case, you want to include the `users` relationship on your `UserContract` model, and the `nonAcceptedContracts` relationship on your `User` model. Simply use dot (`.`) notation on the relationships:

```
return UserContract::with([
  'contracttax',
  'contractproperty',
  'persons',
  'contractwarranty',
  'users.nonAcceptedContracts', // Note: This will include both `users` and `nonAcceptedContracts`
  'contracts',
  'tags'
])->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
->get();
```

Now, when iterating your `UserContract` results, you can access `users` and `nonAcceptedContracts`:

```
foreach ($userContracts as $userContract) {
  foreach ($userContract->users as $user) {
    // Do something with `$user->nonAcceptedContracts` ...
  }
}
```

See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading for full information